# Returned interface{} type assertion

Tags: go, reflection, interface

I need function that make query to database.

I use github.com/gocraft/dbr, so i create helper function:

```
//SelectData - selects data from database
func SelectData(table, fields, where string, data interface{}) interface{} {

    var ptr reflect.Value

    ptr = reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(data)) // create new pointer

    obj := ptr.Interface()

    sess := Session

    query := sess.Select(fields).
        From(table)

    if len(where) > 0 {
        query.Where(where)
    }

    _, err := query.Load(obj)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return obj

}
```

then i try to use it:

```
//CheckUser - checks is user registered in db
func CheckUser(userid string) User {
    var user User
    var i interface{}

    i = db.SelectData("users", "*", "", user)

    fmt.Printf("=%#v \n", i)

    user = i.(User)
    return user
}
```

But i get runtime error:

```
interface conversion: interface {} is *models.User, not models.User
D:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:513 (0x42ccb6)
        gopanic: reflectcall(nil, unsafe.Pointer(d.fn), deferArgs(d), uint32(d.siz), uint32(d.siz))
D:/Go/src/runtime/iface.go:248 (0x4091ac)
        panicdottypeE: panic(&TypeAssertionError{iface, have, want, ""})
C:/Users/vasalt/go/src/wcenter/models/model_user.go:29 (0x9dda3a)
        CheckUser: user = i.(User)
C:/Users/vasalt/go/src/wcenter/controllers/ctrl_main.go:59 (0x9e03b6)
        SetPageData: fmt.Printf("=result = %#v\n", models.CheckUser("1234"))
```

And debug output:

```
=&models.User{UID:sql.NullString{String:"1", Valid:true}, UserID:sql.NullString{String:"1234", Valid:true}, UserGroup:sql.NullString{String:"1", Valid:true}}
```

So it succesfully retrieve data from datbase, but it return `&models.User` not just `models.User` and i cant figure out how convert `interface{}` with `*models.User` to `models.User`

Comment: nope models\model_user.go:29:7: cannot use i.(*User) (type *User) as type User in assignment

Comment: var user User should be `var user *User`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work. You can typecast it to *User and return User value or *User depending on your use case.

```
user = i.(*User)
return *user
```

Comment: Thx, i just change return value `return i.(*User)` and all works just fine

Answer (score 1):

```
 ptr = reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(data)) // create new pointer

 obj := ptr.Interface()
```

`reflect.New` returns a reflect.value representing a pointer to a new data-type entity.and `ptr.Interface()` returns a real value of `ptr` of which type is *data.
So when you invoke `i = db.SelectData("users", "*", "", user)`,it will returns *User.You can't use type assertion `i.(User)` except `i.(*User)`.